# Why do const shared_ptr<const T>& and const shared_ptr<T>& show different reference counts?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, shared-ptr

For the following code snippet, it shows different reference counts in the methods. Could someone explain why these values are different?

```
class Foo {
};

void f1( const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& ptr ) {
   std::cout << "f1(): counts: " << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
}

void f2( const std::shared_ptr<const Foo>& ptr ) {
   std::cout << "f2(): counts: " << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr( new Foo );
   std::cout << "main(): counts: " << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;

   f1( ptr );
   f2( ptr );

   std::cout << "main(): counts: " << ptr.use_count() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The corresponding output:

```
main(): counts: 1
f1(): counts: 1
f2(): counts: 2
main(): counts: 1
```

Comment: It's likely that the f2 call had to construct an implicit temporary object as part of converting from shared_ptr<Foo> to shared_ptr<const Foo>, and that is where the second refcount is coming from when f2 is executing.

Comment: Thanks! Make sense.

Comment: Not at all related, simply FYI: You should [use `make_shared` instead of `new`](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/)

Comment: The underlying reason is that C++ has no covariance on class template parameters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` and `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` are different types (i.e. the class template instantiations with different template type arguments are different types).

When you pass `ptr` (i.e. a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`) to `f2`, it can't be bound to reference to `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` directly; a temporary `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` has to be constructed and then bound to the parameter `ptr`. The constructed `shared_ptr` shares ownership with the original `shared_ptr`, so use_count is increased to `2` in `f2()`.

The temporary will be destroyed when `f2( ptr );` ends; then use_count is decreased to `1`.

Comment: I changed the initialization to `std::shared_ptr<const Foo> ptr( new Foo );` and called `f2( ptr )`. Now I can see that the refcount is not incremented. 

Much appreciated!

Comment: @ArupRatonRoy Yes, for this case no temporary makes trouble.